# Multisite - Multiple logo?

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite with 3 sub-sites. Is it possible to have a different logo for the 3rd sub-site, while keeping the same theme?

ie:

```
Site1 -> Logo One
Site2 -> Logo One
Site3 -> Logo TWO
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please expand your question. What kind of logo do you mean - header image or favicon? How do you currently display the logo?

Comment: Yes, the header logo, currently displayed via header.php as: `<a href="#"><div id="logo"><img src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/logo.jpg'></div></a>`

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/191241/edit) to add in the detail you've posted in a comment. It's best to have as much detail as possible in the question, not in the comments, and it'll make your code more legible too.

Answer (score 2):

The possibilities to set a favicon are different. I think the best way is about a plugin. Also here give it more possibilities.

1. You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/johnbillion/wp-site-icon), that enhance the customizer to set a Favicon.
2. Use [this plugin](https://github.com/bueltge/wordpress-multisite-enhancements), enhance more as only the favicon
3. Custom plugin, see the code hints below. The follow example set a favicon from the theme path of each blog. The path to the stylesheet (`get_stylesheet_directory*`) is the key here. You can also change this path to your requiremtents.

   ```
   add_action( 'wp_head', 'fb_set_favicon' );
   /**
    * Set Favicon from theme directory
    */
   function fb_set_favicon() {

       $stylesheet_dir_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
       $stylesheet_dir     = get_stylesheet_directory();
       $favicon            = '/favicon.ico';
       $output             = '';

       if ( file_exists( $stylesheet_dir . $favicon ) ) {
           $output .= '<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="'
               . esc_url( $stylesheet_dir_uri . $favicon ) . '" />';
           $output .= '<style>';
       }

       echo $output;
   }
   ```
4. It is also possible to set a favicon for each site in the network. But a switch about each site is non performant, is heavy for the system. You find a solution for this scenario in [this class](https://github.com/bueltge/wordpress-multisite-enhancements/blob/master/inc/autoload/class-add-admin-favicon.php), that switch about all sites in the network and add a favicon to the admin bar, each site get a icon.

Comment: I'm not sure OP meant *favicons or site-icons*? But it will be interesting to follow the [core implementation](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/06/10/site-icon-and-image-cropping-controls/) of site icons.

Comment: Thank you for that great answer, however birgire is correct - I don't mean favicon, but rather the actual logo specified in header.php. So either an IF statement based on which site it is (if possible?), or using the same theme but a different header.php file.